# Plot the Percent of time played together

Tags: python, r, python-3.x

I am hoping someone can give me an idea or a solution to the problem I have below. I have been trying to figure out how I can find the percentage a player played with another based off `start time`, `end time`, and `period`(or any other stat I did not mention). I can sum the `duration` of each player in a pivot table to see the full ice time of a player But for the life of me I cannot seem to figure out the other. Whether it needs to be in R, Excel, or a python script I have exhausted my ideas. I know this is not a straight forward scripting question but I can't think of a better spot to pose the question. I can clearly see in example 1 Suter and Dumba played together twice in the small snippet of data i provided. But to plot that on a graph or just find the percentage is where I am asking for any ideas. Below are 2 examples of how i can access OnIce data.

Example 1.   At the end of the period/game I can get the prior Line Shift data. LastName of player will appear multiple times throughout the df.

```
    LastName  StartTime  EndTime  Duration ShiftNumber Period
    Foligno      0:00       0:40    0:40           1    1
    Suter        0:00       0:40    0:40           1    1
    Staal        0:00       0:40    0:40           1    1
    Niederreiter 0:00       0:40    0:40           1    1
    Dubnyk       0:00       20:00   20:00          1    1
    Dumba        0:00       0:40    0:40           1    1
    Zucker       0:40       1:26    0:46           1    1
    Koivu        0:40       1:34    0:54           1    1
    Murphy       0:40       1:26    0:46           1    1
    Brodin       0:40       1:26    0:46           1    1
    Granlund     0:40       1:39    0:59           1    1
    Reilly       1:26       2:09    0:43           1    1
    Winnik       1:26       2:18    0:52           1    1
    Coyle        1:34       2:16    0:42           1    1
    Stewart      1:39       2:13    0:34           1    1
    Dumba        2:09       2:39    0:30           2    1
    Suter        2:09       2:39    0:30           2    1
```

Example 2. I can run a script every couple seconds and save to a csv what player id's are OnIce at the same time.

```
HomePlayerId HomeDuration
8475744        94
8471702        74
8477944        69
8475163        74
8474651        623
8477043        74
HomePlayerId HomeDuration
8475744        111
8471702        91
8477944        86
8475163        91
8474651        640
8477043        91
```

Comment: Can you make your example reproducible, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plain Python code below computes the total amount of overlapping time for each pair of players. The core idea is that given a (start1, end1) interval for player1 and (start2, end2) for player2 then the overlap of those two intervals is

```
overlap = min(end1, end2) - max(start1, start2)
```

if `overlap` <= 0 then there's no overlap for those intervals. We need to perform that computation for every pair of intervals for each pair of players.

```py
from itertools import combinations, product

#LastName   StartTime  EndTime  Duration ShiftNumber Period
data = '''\
Foligno       0:00      0:40    0:40           1    1
Suter         0:00      0:40    0:40           1    1
Staal         0:00      0:40    0:40           1    1
Niederreiter  0:00      0:40    0:40           1    1
Dubnyk        0:00      20:00   20:00          1    1
Dumba         0:00      0:40    0:40           1    1
Zucker        0:40      1:26    0:46           1    1
Koivu         0:40      1:34    0:54           1    1
Murphy        0:40      1:26    0:46           1    1
Brodin        0:40      1:26    0:46           1    1
Granlund      0:40      1:39    0:59           1    1
Reilly        1:26      2:09    0:43           1    1
Winnik        1:26      2:18    0:52           1    1
Coyle         1:34      2:16    0:42           1    1
Stewart       1:39      2:13    0:34           1    1
Dumba         2:09      2:39    0:30           2    1
Suter         2:09      2:39    0:30           2    1
'''.splitlines()

def to_secs(ms):
    ''' Convert a mm:ss string to seconds '''
    m, s = map(int, ms.split(':'))
    return 60 * m + s

# Store a list of (start, end) times for each player
players = {}
for row in data:
    name, start, end = row.split(None, 3)[:3]
    times = to_secs(start), to_secs(end)
    players.setdefault(name, []).append(times)

for t in players.items():
    print(t)
print()

# Determine the amount of overlapping time for each pair of players
for p1, p2 in combinations(sorted(players), 2):
    total = 0
    # Check each pair of times for this pair of players
    for t1, t2 in product(players[p1], players[p2]):
        # Compute the overlap in this pair of times and
        # add it to the total for this pair of players
        start, end = zip(t1, t2)
        total += max(0, min(end) - max(start))
    if total:
        print(p1, p2, total)
```

**output**

```
('Foligno', [(0, 40)])
('Suter', [(0, 40), (129, 159)])
('Staal', [(0, 40)])
('Niederreiter', [(0, 40)])
('Dubnyk', [(0, 1200)])
('Dumba', [(0, 40), (129, 159)])
('Zucker', [(40, 86)])
('Koivu', [(40, 94)])
('Murphy', [(40, 86)])
('Brodin', [(40, 86)])
('Granlund', [(40, 99)])
('Reilly', [(86, 129)])
('Winnik', [(86, 138)])
('Coyle', [(94, 136)])
('Stewart', [(99, 133)])

Brodin Dubnyk 46
Brodin Granlund 46
Brodin Koivu 46
Brodin Murphy 46
Brodin Zucker 46
Coyle Dubnyk 42
Coyle Dumba 7
Coyle Granlund 5
Coyle Reilly 35
Coyle Stewart 34
Coyle Suter 7
Coyle Winnik 42
Dubnyk Dumba 70
Dubnyk Foligno 40
Dubnyk Granlund 59
Dubnyk Koivu 54
Dubnyk Murphy 46
Dubnyk Niederreiter 40
Dubnyk Reilly 43
Dubnyk Staal 40
Dubnyk Stewart 34
Dubnyk Suter 70
Dubnyk Winnik 52
Dubnyk Zucker 46
Dumba Foligno 40
Dumba Niederreiter 40
Dumba Staal 40
Dumba Stewart 4
Dumba Suter 70
Dumba Winnik 9
Foligno Niederreiter 40
Foligno Staal 40
Foligno Suter 40
Granlund Koivu 54
Granlund Murphy 46
Granlund Reilly 13
Granlund Winnik 13
Granlund Zucker 46
Koivu Murphy 46
Koivu Reilly 8
Koivu Winnik 8
Koivu Zucker 46
Murphy Zucker 46
Niederreiter Staal 40
Niederreiter Suter 40
Reilly Stewart 30
Reilly Winnik 43
Staal Suter 40
Stewart Suter 4
Stewart Winnik 34
Suter Winnik 9
```

Comment: Wow, that’s an awesome start, thank you for spending the time to write that. Question for you, if I wanted to calculate more than 2 players at a time, say 6 because usually there are the 5 skaters and 1 goalie OnIce at the same time would I just add more to combinations? As in p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6?

Comment: @MichaelTJohnson Theoretically, we could modify my code to handle that, but it would get rather slow since there are _lots_ of 6 way combinations to chug through. But I guess we could improve the efficiency if the program can identify goalie, so that it only creates combos containing exactly 1 goalie. But yes, the basic principle would still work: for a given group of players we subtract the max of their start times from the min of their end times.

Comment: If I update the data to have there positions that would be something we could write in? I added position to it.

Comment: @MichaelTJohnson It would be better to write a fresh question, and link it back to this one. It's not good to change a question after it's got one or more relevant answers.

Comment: My apologies, I’ll do that! Thank you sir